# Adding two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

First of all, I have some background in highschool mathematics but don't know probabilities at all. So, if I have two random variables X and Y, and sample space = {a, b}, and X : {a, b} -> {0, 1}, Y: {a, b} -> {0, 1} (and their distributions), what is (X + Y)'s distribution? Let's suppose I have the probability function P : {a, b} -> {0.5} (actually it's R, but let's say that P(a) = P(b) = 0.5). Let's say that X(a) = Y(a) = 0, and X(b) = Y(b) = 1, so (X + Y) (a) = 0, (X + Y) (b) = 2. So P(X + Y = 1) = 0. In my course it says that it would be P(X = 0, Y = 1) + P(X = 1, Y = 0) = P(X = 0) * P(Y = 1) + P(X = 1) * P(Y = 0) which is = 0.25 + 0.25 = 0.5. It says that something like this happens if the variables are independent (it isn't yet defined what it means that two random variables are independent). Aren't X and Y independent? Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to consider all the possible cases for values that X and Y could take in a simple 2 by 2 table. Then, for each case, calculate the probability of a joint outcome (e.g. $X=a, Y=b$) as the product of the probabilities, assuming they are independent$^1$. Finally, work out the value of the sum in each of the four cases of the table. Write out a list of the possible sums of $X$ and $Y$ and their respective probabilities; this will be your distribution.

$^1$If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, you must use Bayes' rule and be given the conditional probabilities, if none of this makes sense to you because you were not taught this, then just assume independence.

Comment: I understood the table rule, but my question is, are my X and Y independent ? I guess not, cause the table rule doesnt't work, but why? I didn't get to Baye's rule in the course, but thank you, I will keep in mind

Comment: You need cond. probs if they are not independent you're not given that then you can only back-engineer their lack of independence if the table (!) is already worked out for you

Comment: Let's say that X(a) = Y(a) = 0, and X(b) = Y(b) = 1, so (X + Y) (a) = 0, (X + Y) (b) = 2. So P(X + Y = 1) = 0.

The joint distribution is worked out here a half-chance of the sum being nought, and a half chance of it being two

Comment: Thanks, from the way it was exposed in my course I understood (or at least doubted, as long as no formal definition for independent variables was given) that we can magically attribute this property of independence to any two random variables. Generally, we were given two random and affirmed without any proof that they are independent, so that's why I thought like that. THX

Comment: You have the formal definition: that the probability of a joint outcome is the product of the probabilities of each random variable, implies the random variables are independent

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generally solve for the distribution of $X+Y$ unless you know the *joint* distribution of $(X,Y).$ When random variables are discrete, this means you should know $P(X=x,Y=y)\forall x,y$, i.e. the probability assigned to every tuple $(x,y).$

Your random variables are *Bernoulli* random variables (i.e. they only take values zero or one.) So to find the probability mass function of $S=X+Y$, you would sum the joint probabilities of $(X,Y)$ across all $(X,Y)$ s.t. $X+Y=S$:

$$P(X+Y=s)=\sum_{x}P(X=x,Y=s-x)\\
\implies P(X+Y=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)\\
P(X+Y=1)=P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0)\\
P(X+Y=2)=P(X=1,Y=1).$$

If discrete $X,Y$ are [independent](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter3/3_1_4_independent_random_var.php), this means $P(X=x,Y=Y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y).$ Thus, you can obtain the joint distribution (and hence the distribution of the sum of $X+Y$) just by knowing the *marginal* distributions of $X,Y.$

Comment: Pls look at this website for an introductory crash course on this material: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter3/3_1_4_independent_random_var.php